# Showing points as one big point

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, zoom, display

I've already made a map in QGIS, but the problem is that all the points of the coordinates are concentrated in one area in the map and I have to zoom in to see that it is several points. Is there any possible way to clearly see the points without zooming in?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 12):

Use `Point Cluster` rendering style - where points are closer then a certain distance (`7 Millimeters` in the screenshot), it will not show individual points, but a separate symbol indicating the number of points inside this cluster.

*To change the appearance/style of this symbol (red circle with number) like size, color etc., click on the icon with the `A` next to `Cluster symbol`:*
[image]

Comment: Another option is to use the "Point displacement" renderer that put the points on a circle or on a grid to avoid overlap